# Не работает опция --headless в selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Код бота полностью работает , но когда я ставлю опцию --headless он не может найти указанные элементы `

```
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("путь к файлу", options=options)

    def login(self):    
        browser = self.browser
        browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
        time.sleep(random.randrange(3, 5))

        username_input = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
        username_input.clear()
        username_input.send_keys(username)

        time.sleep(2)

        password_input = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
        password_input.clear()
        password_input.send_keys(password)

        password_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/button/div").click()
        time.sleep(10)`
```

Вот что выводит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Danila/Desktop/Личный проект/Instagram_bot/main.py", line 454, in <module>
    my_bot.login()
  File "c:/Users/Danila/Desktop/Личный проект/Instagram_bot/main.py", line 38, in login
    username_input = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
  File "C:\Users\Danila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 496, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\Danila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Danila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Danila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="username"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

---

[image: Нашел проблему,но как решить не знаю]

Вот что получается когда запускаю с headless возможно нужно что-то сделать с самим браузером но я пока не знаю что

Comment: А почему вы подумали на `headless`? Судя по трассе стека у вас ошибка была в `username_input = browser.find_element_by_name("username")` и потому что не удалось найти элемент, что написано в исключении `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`. Возможно, элемент не успел прогрузиться, попробуйте добавить неявное ожидание: `self.driver.implicitly_wait(10) `

Comment: Потому что без использования headless все работает

Comment: Ну хз, мб без отображения окна, область рендера стала меньше (размер страницы), поэтому тот элемент не успел появиться или нужно к нему теперь переместиться или сделать скролл...

Comment: `options.headless = True`

Answer (score 2):

Большинство случаев неправильной работы с --headless у меня были связаны с проверкой сертификата SSL. Попробуйте добавить в код игнор ошибки:

```
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
```

Или добавьте все сразу:

```
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
```

постепенно удаляя ненужное.

Comment: Попробовал так сделать не помогло(

Comment: @Mimoza23 может не успевает прогрузиться? поставьте паузу time.sleep(2) больше?

Comment: Все равно нет результата , я там добавил какую ошибку выводит , он почему-то не находит элементы

Comment: @Mimoza23 без add_argument('--headless') точно работает? :)

Comment: попробуйте найти username_input (и пасс, потом) не по имени, а по пути: browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']") ?

Comment: Точно такая же ошибка(

Comment: да без add_argument('--headless') работает

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему тем что перешёл с Chrome на Firefox